# How to debug WooCommerce shipping packages

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, e-commerce

My WooCommerce store is using the [Packages Configuration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/packages-configuration-for-woocommerce/) plugin to split orders into various packages based on their WC `shipping_class`.

How can I precisely debug the shipping calculations? For example, my shipping class formula `[qty]` results in twice the expected amount, and each package shows its items twice.

I'd like to figure out what's causing the duplicated products to appear in the shipping calculation. How can that be done?